# Не запускается проект на Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image: тут должен быть значок андроида]
[image: тут должна быть опция run]
[image: тут должна быть опция build variant]

у меня не запускается проект который скачал через гит. нету кнопки run чтобы запустить на эмуляторе. внизу с лева должен быть Build variant где я выбираю какой конкретно проект хочу запустить. помогите разобраться плс.

---

написано что нету модуля......
[image: написано что нету модуля]

gradlew.bat: The term 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Suggestion [3,General]: The command gradlew.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\gradlew.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Ошибка выше вызвана командой gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug.
Но я не понял где нужно менять путь

Comment: сначала нужно создать конфигурацию для запуска - кнопка Add Configuration

Comment: написано что нету модуля

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @TimHalli, возможно версия Android Studio не подружилась с версией андроид-плагина в проекте. Чтобы узнать наверняка, попробуйте запустить сборку проекта из командной строки с помощью команды `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` (либо `gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug` для Windows) и приложите [прямо в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1475392/edit) все ошибки, которые будут на выходе.